# What is the transcriptome in layman's term?

Tags: bioinformatics, homework, rna, transcription, mrna

I am new to the bioinformatics field and am trying to understand a research paper that includes some terminology without definitions. The term transcriptome in particular is banded around in the literature, but is not clearly defined.

Can someone provide a reference or source to guide me to some learning material where I can get the basics.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Biology SE. Can you please clarify and refine your question? I`m not quite sure what you're asking, although I believe you would like to know what Transcription in RNA is.

Comment: Doesn't googling "transcriptome", help?

Comment: I've given a layman answer. With that information in mind you'll see that this is a big field and without the specific paper you had in mind, answering this question in the most helpful way isn't possible.

Comment: I would strongly recommend getting an introductory textbook such as Bruce Alberts' [Molecular Biology of the Cell](http://www.amazon.com/Molecular-Biology-Cell-Bruce-Alberts/dp/0815344325) to help you understand all the various terms you are going to come across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three "omic" definitions that might help you.

The DNA is the long term storage of the information. You're probably familiar with this concept, and the study of this type of information is **genomics**.

One of the major functions of DNA is it's use as the blueprint for the production of proteins. Proteins carry out all sorts of structural and functional roles in the cell. Which proteins are present at a certain times and locations is known as the proteome. This is studied in **proteomics**.

Inbetween the DNA and the protein is an intermediate step. The DNA is *transcribed* to RNA, and then the RNA is *translated* to the protein. During the transcription of DNA to RNA, certain sequences of the DNA are not transcribed to RNA for a variety of reasons. The study of what exactly is transcribed at what time in which locations is **transcriptomics**.

Comment: Also to include RNAs that do not give rise to proteins, DNA also serves as a blueprint for their synthesis.